# I can't use the value returned from promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I write the code to fetch data from my api. In the first time I code this.[image]

and then I get the result. It's ok[image]

But after that I want to use that value. I code this
[image]

It shown me the error.
[image]

I tried read about promise and async,await a lot but it didn't help me. Please enlighten me.

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = React.useState("");
  const testGetData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("/api/products/test").then((response) => {
      return response;
    });
    return data;
  };
 let productData = [];

 testGetData().then((response)=>{
   return response.json();
 }).then((res)=>{
    productData.push(res);
 });

console.log(productData);
console.log(productData[0].productName);
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>{stateData}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question instead of using a screenshot of it.

Comment: `productData` is initially an empty array. So `productData[0]` is not available ( `undefined` ). So you are trying `productData[0].productName` which means you are trying to access the property `productName` of undefined

Comment: You need to use `setStateData(res)` instead of `productData.push(res)` to cause a re-render. And you need to put the `fetchData()` call in an `useEffect` hook.

Comment: the data is async so you need to wait until the data is ready, before to try to read it.

Comment: sorry for screenshot post. I will avoid screenshot asking next time. I will try setState and How can I wait data to be ready to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use the state to store the data from the request

Secondly, to get the data, the request needs to be wrapped in a useEffect. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Here is a good article describing how to get data asynchronously using hooks https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data